# Safari --> "Application Cache manifest had an incorrect MIME type: text/plain."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-cache

> "Application Cache manifest had an incorrect MIME type: text/plain."

Getting the same message again and again yet I get my content cached.
Browsers on which I am facing this problem: IE9/10 and Safari.
My Mozilla and chrome gives and output fine.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function logEvent(event) {
      alert(event.type);
  }

  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('checking',logEvent,false);
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate',logEvent,false);
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('downloading',logEvent,false);    
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('cached',logEvent,false);
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready',logEvent,false);
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('obsolete',logEvent,false);
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('error',logEvent,false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIME type should be `text/cache-manifest`. This is required on old browsers.

> This requirement was dropped from the specification some time ago, and no longer required by the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but you'll need the mime-type to work in older browsers and IE11.

[A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)